# Query to Sum Numbers Based on Location (State)

Tags: sql, join, sum

I'm trying to write a query that will summarize all of the procedures performed during the calendar year 2013, whether the event happened on a mobile drive or at a fixed site within a particular state.

Every Drive is Unique and will either occur at a Fixed Site (CenterID) or on a Mobile Site, which are associated with Accounts (AccountID). My query looks like this:

```
select sum(proceduresperformed), sum(productscollected)
from DriveProjectionAndCollectedTotals DPaCT
inner join rpt_DriveMaster DM on DPaCT.DriveID=DM.DriveID
left outer join rpt_Accounts Acct on DM.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
left outer join rpt_CenterDetail CD on DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID
inner join rpt_AddressDetail AD on Acct.AccountID=AD.AccountID
inner join rpt_AddressDetail AD2 on CD.CenterID=AD2.CenterID
where AD.State='FL'
or AD2.State='FL'
and Year(DM.FromDateTime)=2013
```

But these numbers are really high and incorrect.  So what I did was remove one of the joins (either the Account or the CenterDetail) and run the query twice to get numbers that look much more in line with what is expected:

```
select sum(proceduresperformed), sum(productscollected)
from DriveProjectionAndCollectedTotals DPaCT
inner join rpt_DriveMaster DM on DPaCT.DriveID=DM.DriveID
left outer join rpt_Accounts Acct on DM.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
--left outer join rpt_CenterDetail CD on DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID
inner join rpt_AddressDetail AD on Acct.AccountID=AD.AccountID
--inner join rpt_AddressDetail AD2 on CD.CenterID=AD2.CenterID
where AD.State='FL'
--or AD2.State='FL'
and Year(DM.FromDateTime)=2013
```

How can I fix the original query to summarize the two columns in a way that does not basically triple the expected value?

The original query returns:
[image: Original Query Summary]

And running the query with Accounts and Centers separately:
[image: Individual Summaries]

Comment: You would appear to be doing joins along different dimensions of the data.  The results in a cartesian product.  Well, that's the problem.  It is not really possible to say anything about how to fix it without sample data and data layouts.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, what can I provide for assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and used a UNION statement to give me the correct answer:

```
select sum(procperf) as 'Procedures Performed'
from (
select sum(proceduresperformed) as procperf
from DriveProjectionAndCollectedTotals DPaCT
inner join rpt_DriveMaster DM on DPaCT.DriveID=DM.DriveID
left outer join rpt_Accounts Acct on DM.AccountID=Acct.AccountID
inner join rpt_AddressDetail AD on Acct.AccountID=AD.AccountID
where AD.State='FL'
and Year(DM.FromDateTime)=2013
UNION
select sum(proceduresperformed) as procperf
from DriveProjectionAndCollectedTotals DPaCT
inner join rpt_DriveMaster DM on DPaCT.DriveID=DM.DriveID
left outer join rpt_CenterDetail CD on DM.CenterID=CD.CenterID
inner join rpt_AddressDetail AD2 on CD.CenterID=AD2.CenterID
where AD2.State='FL'
and Year(DM.FromDateTime)=2013
) as a;
```

Comment: May I ask why Union All should be used over Union?

Comment: `UNION` adds an additional step of removing duplicates.  This is wasteful at best.  In this case, it could remove one of the rows if they have the same value.